# How to debug npm? Why it stopped working after reinstalling all dependencies?

Tags: node.js, npm

I have been running a project with npm for about 4 months without big issues.

Until today, when I had the terrible idea to try to update the `react-redux` lib to the last version.

Turned out that it didn't work and I just discarded the changes I've made to the `package.json` and installed everything again:

`git checkout package.json
rm -rf node_modules
npm install`

But now, when I run the server I get this error:

`Error: Cannot find module 'bootstrap' from '/Users/rodrigora/Projects/PROJ/node_modules/react-bootstrap-multiselect/dist'`

This doesn't make sense, because I discarded all changes.

Why it stopped to work?
What can I do to try to identify what is causing this?

Thanks

**Edit:**

npm version: 5.1.0

**Solution**

After about 2 hours I did this:

```
rm -rf node_modules/react-bootstrap-multiselect
npm install bootstrap
npm install react-bootstrap-multiselect
```

and it worked! **Yah, NPM is a great dependency manager!**

Thank you all!

Comment: One possibility is that you unintentionally installed a different version of `react-bootstrap-multiselect` (whatever that is).  Another possibility is that you haven't had it in your `package.json` for a very long time.  If either turns out to be the issue, you should upgrade to NPM 5 or Yarn (whichever is currently less buggy), because they both create lock-files which help avoid these scenarios.

Comment: Which version of npm are you using? What's in your package.json? To what versions have you attempted to upgrade, and how exactly didn't it work?

Comment: @E_net4 Thank you for your response. I was trying to solve a performance issue but didn't work. So I decided to keep the same dependencies as before. I'm using the last NPM version

Comment: Travel into `/Users/rodrigora/Projects/PROJ/node_modules/react-bootstrap-multiselect` and run `npm install` (FYI, I posted this comment before your last solution edit, I didn't just repeat what you said! lol)

Comment: Please move your solution to an answer, so that future visitors quickly find how you solved the problem.

Comment: As a final remark, don't forget that npm is usually spelled "npm", and not "NPM" (unless everything else around it is in upper case).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's what worked for me:

```
rm -rf node_modules/react-bootstrap-multiselect
npm install bootstrap
npm install react-bootstrap-multiselect
```

Answer (score -4):

It sounds like you just need to import the bootstrap library, try looking through http://getbootstrap.com/ for what you need.

Comment: Hi @user3688675, that is what npm is intended to do

Comment: Presumably, he already had bootstrap installed. The question is, why is it not able to find it after reinstalling the modules.

Comment: I believe I misunderstood the question then.